Failed to initialize tesseract engine in visual studio
I am currently trying to build an application that use an ocr to take text from an image and paste said text into a label. I am trying to use tesseract for this however it is driving me insane. There is no clear-cut direction on what to download or where to place files. I have tesseract 5 installed in the nuget packages and I've tried multiple different tesseract files from github to get the correct data in the tessdata folder but nothing has worked.
Can someone please provide me direction on how to properly integrate tesseract into a visual studio environment for proper use?
Here is part of the code by the way
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata","eng", EngineMode.Default))

I've tried different tesseract folders from github, different file names for the path, literally everything I need help

I have tesseract 5 installed in the nuget packages: For Github and NuGet it's important to specify exactly which one you are using because similar packages/projects/solutions often exist. It's unclear which NuGet package that you are attempting to use.

Nuget is Tesseract 5.2.0, should i be getting 5.2.0 on github as well?

Click on the NuGet URL in my previous comment, search for the package that you are using, and then include the URL to the package in your post so we know exactly what NuGet package that you're using.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract

On the right side of that page, did you click Project Website, scroll down to where it states: Getting started quickly and follow the instructions?
